# Problem when creating aditional users

Tags: permissions, adduser

I just upgraded to ubuntu 11.04. I've no issues with creating users, but if they login an error occurs. For example, when I create the user "luli" and login with that user, I got the error:

> Could not update ICEauthority file
>   /home/luli/.ICEauthority

I can only see the cursor and the background, then:

> There is a problem with the
>   configuration server.
>   (usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2
>   exited with state 256)

Then a notification shows up an the right up corner:

> Could not apply the stored
>   configuration for monitor.

And finally another error message:

> Nautilus could not create the
>   following folders:  /home/luli/Desktop
>   and /home/luli/.nautilus. Before
>   running nautilus, please create this
>   folders, or set permissions such that
>   Nautilus can create them.

Then nothing else happens, and I have to restart the computer.
I looked for this error on the internet and someone said that fixed with changing permissions to the folders manually.
I created those folders, as said on the last error message, and set the permissions using:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/luli/
sudo chown luli:luli /home/luli/
```

Then i copied the archive `.ICEauthority` form my personal user folder, to the new user's folder and used this:

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/luli/.ICEauthority
sudo chown luli:luli /home/luli/.ICEauthority
```

And i got nothing to change, it still not work. I have to add that a couple of days ago i moved the /home folder to its own partition, in order to have my files more independent from the system. I did that following this steps: http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How did you create the user? With `sudo useradd user`? (which is the wrong command) Also note that you shouldn't copy `.ICE*` or `.Xauthority` files.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: I was interested why `useradd` is wrong and what should be used instead (as per @Lekensteyn's comment). I found an answer at <http://askubuntu.com/a/98337/19753>.