# How does "Accounts Service" work with lightdm?

Tags: login-screen, lightdm, adduser

I have added two users using the command `useradd` but they do no show up in the lightdm/unity-greeter login screen. So there is no way to graphically login for them.  It seems Accounts Service (whatever that is) is not reading them in. How can I reload that or cause them to appear in the login window?  I am a Fedora user so I have no clue about Ubuntu and how it does these things. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu the recommended command to add a new user to the system is

```
sudo adduser <newuser> --ingroup <group>
```

This will take care to add this new user to the system with settings defined in `/etc/adduser.conf`.

The low-level command `useradd` is available but not all default settings are made

> **useradd** is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use **adduser(8)** instead.<sup>from manpage useradd</sup>

Answer (score 3):

According to the package information:

> The `accountsservice` project provides a set of D-Bus interfaces for querying and manipulating user account information and an implementation of these interfaces, based on the `useradd`, `usermod` and `userdel` commands.

So, based on this information it seems that the only way to configure it is to configure those base services (`usermod`, `useradd` and `userdel`) which can be accomplished by editing the `/etc/login.defs` file. Specifically **if you're looking for a way to show a user whose ID is lower than 1000** you have to change the value of MIN_UID.

It seems that the `/etc/login.defs` file is used in two ways:

1. To control defaults when accounts are created.
2. To control how the `accountsservice` accounts-daemon responds to D-Bus queries.

#### Short answer

Since ubuntu sets a user's group (GID) to be the same value as the user's ID (UID) I found that I had to alter both MIN_UID and MIN_GID in `/etc/login.defs` to get `accountsservice` to reveal my login to lightdm.